# Send email via ajax

Tags: ajax, email

I have send email funciton on my home.php wordpress file and function is below

```
$("#sendmailbtn").click(function(e) {
    var dataString = $(".pricing").html();
    e.preventDefault();
    var grandTotal = localStorage.getItem("GrandTotal");
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
    datatype: "html",
    data: {'action': 'fahadsending_mail', 'more': dataString, 'grandTotal': grandTotal},
    success: function(response) {
        alert("success is " + response);
    },error:function(response){
        alert("error is " + response);
    }
    });
});
```

AND THE EMAIL CODE IN MY functions.php file is below where i am sending post to fahadsending_mail function but it ajax success function it alerts success is 0

```
    add_action('wp_ajax_fahadsending_mail', 'fahadsending_mail');
add_action('wp_ajax_fahadsending_mail', 'fahadsending_mail');

function fahadsending_mail(){

        $to = "asadkhan6164995@gmail.com";
        $subject = "Donation";
        $message = "message message message message message message message "; 

        if(wp_mail($to, $subject, $message))
        {
            echo "mail sent";
    } else {
        echo "mail not sent";
    }

}
```

and response comes in success function and it alert success is 0 and ajax post shows following action
wplc_call_to_server_visitor cid 213 security
2f40c8e66f status
5 wplc_email
no email set wplc_name
Guest wplcsession 1456325128583

Answer (score 1):

You need to allow AJAX requests for guests too. Usually when a WordPress AJAX call returns 0, it means that there are no capabilities for the user to perform that action.

Also, your debug info showed `Guest`.

Alter your function to include the `nopriv` AJAX for guests:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_fahadsending_mail', 'fahadsending_mail');
add_action('wp_ajax_fahadsending_mail', 'fahadsending_mail');

function fahadsending_mail(){

    $to = "asadkhan6164995@gmail.com";
    $subject = "Donation";
    $message = "message message message message message message message "; 

    if( wp_mail($to, $subject, $message) ){
        echo "mail sent";
    } else {
        echo "mail not sent";
    }

    die(); // never forget to die() your AJAX reuqests

}
```